# Geolocalisation on iPhone app

Tags: iphone, module

iam developing iPhone application that allow user to define stations near to him, so that, the application should locate the user automatically, iam looking for module that i can integrate in my application to do so (geolocalisation), thx for help. Cordially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at [CoreLocation Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html) and [LocateMe](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007801) sample.